# Highcharts Linechart drawing lines in wrong order

Tags: javascript, angularjs, charts, highcharts

The project Frontend is in angularjs and we are using the highcharts lib for charts.
I have line charts that stopped working correctly after updating from highcharts 5 to highcharts 7. I don't think this is a bug in the highcharts lib itself. when i try to reproduce this behaviour in a small example, i can't. So i assume that some default value or some property changed, that has this side effect.

Point Data:

```
1. x: 1,  y: 21.5
2. x: 12, y: 21.5
3. x: 12, y: 20
4. x: 24, y: 24
```

Result:
[image]

The points are in this order. points 2 and 3 have the same x value and for some reason that is a problem for highcharts. I know this because i made a dirty fix that checks the point x values and detects a step like this and increases the 2nd x value to 12.000001 for example, which then results on the wanted drawing behaviour.

Point Data:

```
1. x: 1,         y: 21.5
2. x: 12,        y: 21.5
3. x: 12.000001, y: 20
4. x: 24,        y: 24
```

Result:
[image]

I check the documentation for an option that could fix it, but i couldn't find anything.
As i don't wanna keep this dirty fix, i hope someone can help me to resolve this.

EDIT: im adding the charts configs

SeriesObject:

```
        var serieObject = {
            data: graph.Data,
            id: graph.Name + "_" + graph.InfoData,
            color: graph.Color,
            name: graph.Description,
            lineWidth: hideLine ? 0 : 1,
            zIndex: 1,
            stickyTracking: false,
            tooltip: {
                followPointer: false
            },
            marker: {
                enabled: hidePoints ? false : true,
                radius: 3
            },
            turboThreshold: 0,
            boostThreshold: 0
        }

        if (hideLine) {
            serieObject.states = {
                hover: {
                    lineWidth: 0,
                    lineWidthPlus: 0
                }
            }
        };
```

ChartObject:

```
    var createBasicChartObject = function (type, title, heigth, argCharacteristic, argViewType) {
        return {
            chart: {
                type: type,
                height: heigth,
                zoomType: "xy",
                animation: false
            },
            credits: false,
            xAxis: {
                 // we set type of xaxis later either to 'datetime' or undefined
            },
            series: [
            ],
            title: {
                text: title
            }
            exporting: {
                buttons: {
                    fallbackToExportServer: false,
                    contextButton: {
                        menuItems: [
                            {
                                text: 'Export to PNG (small)',
                                onclick: function () {                                   
                                    this.exportChart({
                                        width: 250
                                    });
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                text: 'Export to PDF (large)',
                                onclick: function () {
                                    this.exportChart({
                                        type: 'application/pdf'
                                    });
                                }
                            }                             
                        ]
                    }
                }
            },
            boost: {
                useGPUTranslations: true
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: It's difficult to find out the cause of this behavior without viewing the complete chart configuration. I've checked this case in both previous and the latest versions https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/q5z4pfdr/, but as you mentioned, the issue isn't reproducible based solely on the data provided. Could you please share the full configuration for a broader context?

Comment: you're right, i added the chart and series configs

Comment: Thank you for providing the code. Unfortunately, I didn't find any significant properties that could influence this behavior. I would recommend checking this with the newest version of Highcharts (11.4). Perhaps this is a bug that has already been fixed. If that doesn't help, please try to reproduce the issue in an online demo.

Comment: thanks for looking at my problem. im afraid to upgrade to the newest versions since its such a big jump and maybe more stuff will break and i don't really want to spend more time on this problem. so i will probably go with the dirty fix.